# Angular invalid configuration(Webpack)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am learning angular for about a month. I am following a series of video that I've found in internet. I got stuck here in this error as shown in picture below.

[image: Error]

**webpack.server.config.js code**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: { server: './server.ts' },
resolve: { extentions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
externals: [/{node_modules|main\..*\.js}/],
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
    rules: {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
    }
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
        path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        {}
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
        path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        {}
    )
  ]
}
```

> Package.json
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clues are right there in the error message. `rules` needs to be an array of objects, not a single object; and `extensions` is spelled with an `s` where you have a second `t`.

Here is the fixed version:

**webpack.server.config.js code**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: { server: './server.ts' },
resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] }, // CHANGED
externals: [/{node_modules|main\..*\.js}/],
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
    rules: [{                           // CHANGED
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
    }]                                  // CHANGED
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
        path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        {}
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
        path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        {}
    )
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I have some error. But I try to solve it.