# XMLHttpRequest is not defined (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

After solving my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729683/angular-invalid-configurationwebpack) problem. I got an error as picture below provided.

[image]

I tried this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891992/referenceerror-xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-when-running-my-angular-6-univers) but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

[image]

> Initialize the firebase
> [image]

> This is how I use it
> [image]

Comment: Have you installed ```xmlhttprequest``` yet?

Comment: @KienNguyen yes I have seen some link that suggest to install it. I tried it but still the same

Comment: Why can't you use like `xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: @Kshitij I'm not using this `XMLHttpRequest `. I think it cause a problem in firebase?. No idea.

Comment: Where's Firebase in your sample code though?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to do with XMLHttpRequest based on the code that you shared, but if you're trying to make a network request from the NodeJS side, using an npm library like "request" or "node-fetch" might be a better route to go. If you're trying to make the request from your angular app, then you shouldn't need to import XMLHttpRequest on the NodeJS side of the app, you should just have access to it as a normal javascript API from the angular client code. More code and explanation would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604460/xmlhttprequest-module-not-defined-found

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably that you're importing the version meant for a browser environment into a Node environment, but the code you've included is insufficient for us to be able to do anything but guess based on our own experiences.

Comment: Sorry, because I'm still studying angular and new to this. I edited my question I hope it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: What if you comment out all mentions of Firebase? Do you still get that error?